# JS Combine array values into one single value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this object

```
a = {key:'animals',
     options: ['dog','cat','penguin']}
```

How can I simplify it to this:

```
b = ['animals','dogcatpenguin']
```

Comment: does your keys are consistent ?

Comment: Iterate over the properties and push their values to a new array. Note however that browser may iterate over properties in different orders. If you always have these properties you can just access them directly. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: You can try `var b = []; b.push(a.key); b.push(a.options.join(''));`

Comment: `var b = new Array(a.key, a.options.join(""));` - It's important to note what @FelixKling says if you intend to iterate, then order of an object's keys is never guaranteed

Comment: I am using this solution for an Angular project and first answer works perfectly. Thank you all:)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like so

```js
var a = {
  key: 'animals',
  options: ['dog','cat','penguin']
};

var key, b = [];

for (key in a) {
  b.push(Array.isArray(a[key]) ? a[key].join('') : a[key]);
}

console.log(b);
```

Or you can use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) with [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var a = {
    key: 'animals',
    options: ['dog','cat','penguin']
};

var b = Object.keys(a).map(function (key) {
    return Array.isArray(a[key]) ? a[key].join('') : a[key];     
});

console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
var a = {
  key: 'animals',
  options: ['dog', 'cat', 'penguin']
}
var result = Object.keys(a).map(function(key){
  var item = a[key];
  return item instanceof Array ? item.join('') : item;
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a new array with your computed values

```js
var a = {key:'animals',
     options: ['dog','cat','penguin']};

var b = [
  a.key,
  a.options.join('')
];

document.write(JSON.stringify(b));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = {
  key: 'animals',
  options: ['dog','cat','penguin']
};

var idx, b = [];

for (idx in a) { //Iterate through all the items of object a
  b.push(Array.isArray(a[key]) ? a[key].join('') : a[key]); //Check if item is array join with (blank) or if not directly push it new array
}

console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution.

```
a = {key:'animals',options: ['dog','cat','penguin']}

var b = new Array();
for(var index in a) { 
    var attr = a[index].toString().split(",").join("");
    b.push(attr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
b = [a.key,Object.values(a)[1].reduce((a,b)=> a+b)]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.